# How do I stop Photoshop from automatically setting defaults?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, tools

I start using Photoshop, and I find that it'll automatically start keeping settings I didn't tell it to. For example, only once I told it I wanted a shape with just an outline, but no fill, and now every single time I want to create a shape, it automatically defaults to a shape with only an outline. I never set it to automatically do this. Another thing, when I set the text to go vertical, it'll automatically set the default for text to go vertical.

How do I stop this behavior, and if there's no way to stop it, how do I set the tool presets back to default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make a change to something without having a document open, then the program makes that as your default from then on. That is consistent across the Adobe suite I believe. I have to guess that that is what you did. If not, then try resetting your preferences next time you open Photoshop. That will probably resolve the issue.

Comment: Update: That totally solved it. Thank you so much, haha. I was getting extremely frustrated over it